# Connect to another container's network stack in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am able to connect to another container's network stack by running this command:

```
docker run -it --net=container:<container name> <container image> bash
```

How something like that can be achieved in Docker Compose?

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    image: ubuntu
    networks:
      - mynet
  attachedclient:
    image: ubuntu
    networks:
      - <???>
networks:
  mynet:
```

What should be added in `???` or somewhere else, so that the `attachedclient` container would connect to `client` container's network stack?

Comment: By default all your containers are on the same network, you don't need to specify `networks` at all. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 0):

simply `mynet`, containers on the same network can communicate